# PHP - use __get with $this

Tags: php, magic-methods

Usually if I have an object `$foo` and I want to intercept the access to one of its property, let's say `bar`, when using `$foo->bar`,  I can use the magic method `__get`.

From what I can see ([here](https://3v4l.org/cVQ8b)) `__get` does not work when interactiong with `$this`. I find this kind of odd and inconsistent.

What is the reason beyond this behaviour?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking..... \_\_get() works with properties that __can't be accessed__ from the calling scope; `$this->a` can be accessed from within `$this`, so it doesn't call `__get()`.... that's not inconsistent at all

Comment: [PHP Docs ref](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) - `__get() is utilized for reading data from __inaccessible properties__.` (my emphasis)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__get()` is only invoked if a property with the given name cannot be found on the object. In your example `$this->a` resolves to the protected property `$a` which is accessible from the context of the class. That's why `__get()` is not called in this case.

This has nothing to do with using `$this`.

```
class A {
    public $a = 'A'; // $a is public

    public function __get($name) {
        return 'B';
    }
}

$a = new A();
var_dump($a->a); // string(1) "A" and not "B"

class B {
    protected $b = 'B'; // $b is protected

    public function __get($name) {
        return 'C';
    }
}

$b = new B();
var_dump($b->b); // string(1) "C" and not "B"

class C1 {
    private $c = 'C';
}    

class C2 extends C1 {
    public function __get($name) {
        return 'D';
    }
}

$c = new C2();
var_dump($c->c); // string(1) "D" and not "C"
```